# XPS 9510: Thunberbolt 4 power and USB-C power via a Dock simultaneously

Tags: dell, 21.04, xps, dock, usb-c

I have the XPS 15 (9510) running Ubuntu 21.04 connected to power via one of the Thunderbolt 4 ports on the left site, occasionally I connect on the right side of the laptop (USB-C), a small dock that also provides power via USB-C PD (it is required to operate the dock), having 2 power sources, will that damage the laptop? Or the laptop will keep using only the TB4 (it was already active when I plugged the dock) and discard the power provided by the dock? Thanks

Comment: Check with the manufacturer. This has nothing to do with Ubuntu or any other OS.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a hardware related question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, please close the thread, thank you